# Rails 3 after_save for tracking history of updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The reason for this post is to get feedback as to whether there's a "Rails Way" of doing what I'm attempting. The way I'm doing it seems a bit clunky and prone to human error.

I have multiple tables which I want to store history of including the time and date a record is updated. Who updates it is not important.

At the moment, I have put together the following [not yet tested, some syntax is probably wrong], but it seems like other people would have this need and that there would be a better way of doing it, whether there was a way of implementing this at the database level instead or some other inbuilt method/callback I'm not aware of.

The model CreateDdiPlanHistorical was generated including updated_at:datetime on top of the other fields seen below in the create_history method, my understanding is that should automatically populate on any records in the historicals table being added or modified.

(validations and associations stripped out for clarity)

```
class CallDdiPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :ddi_count, :plan_name, :price

  after_save :create_history

  private

    def create_history
      CallDdiPlanHistorical.create({:active => this.active, :ddi_count => this.ddi_count, :plan_name => this.plan_name, :price => this.price, :call_ddi_plan_id => this.id})
    end

end
```

Comment: Do you need a history of every update or just the most recent one?

Comment: Every update. This is going to be used to generate historical billing reports, so I need to know when prices changed and what they were at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some sort of roll-your-own solution, but if you really want to make the boss happy, use the audited gem:

```
https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited
```

Comment: I look the look of that, and rolling my own was a last resort, I'd like to think [mostly for the sake of productive laziness] that the DRY principal also applies when there's a freely available gem that does what I need. Thanks Mark.